# angularjs listbox popover

Tags: angularjs, listbox, popover

i am trying to implement a popover on a listbox using angularjs. 
I dont have the idea of where to put the code to implemet popover.
The code:

```
 <select multiple ng-model="leftSelect" size="10" 
  ng-options="c.name for c in List"></select>
```

The popover needs to be shown using the following as attributes.

```
popover="I appeared on mouse enter!" popover-trigger="mouseenter"
```

I have also tried using

```
<option ng-repeat="c in list"></option>.
```

It didnt work.
Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this one

```
<select multiple ng-model="leftSelect" size="10" 
  ng-options="c.name for c in List" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="mouseenter" title="I appeared on mouse enter!"  ></select>
```

Comment: thank u for ur answer. but i need a popover like this [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)

Comment: have u added dependency [ui.bootstrap ] in app. or please if it is possible then post the question in plnkr.